# Date String Conversion to Java Date

Tags: java, data-conversion

I have a string with date in it. I want to convert it into date.
For example

```
    String str = "Fri Oct 23 00:00:00 PKT 2015";
```

How to convert it into java date.

Comment: make use of java.text.SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SimpleDateFormat` class :

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

String dateInString = "7-Jun-2013";

try {

    Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

} catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Output :**

```
Fri Jun 07 00:00:00 MYT 2013
07-Jun-2013
```

Comment: The problem is i have String with "Fri Oct 23 00:00:00 PKT 2015" and i want to convert this string into data. What should be date format for this string.

Comment: I solve it

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

formatter.parse("Fri Oct 23 00:00:00 PKT 2015");